# Is there any way to remove accents and cedillas from string in Tcl?

Tags: regex, unicode, tcl

On a CLi terminal, using *bourn shell* would do:

```
# Remove characters with accents

for n in * 
  do 
    sudo mv "$n" "`echo $n | sed 'y/áÁàÀãÃâÂéÉêÊíÍóÓõÕôÔúÚüÜçÇ/aAaAaAaAeEeEiIoOoOoOuUuUcC/'`"
done
```

---

```
# sed - Removing accented characters
sed 'y/áÁàÀãÃâÂéÉêÊíÍóÓõÕôÔúÚüÜçÇ/aAaAaAaAeEeEiIoOoOoOuUuUcC/'
```

---

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*" | grep -E '[áÁàÀãÃâÂéÉêÊíÍóÓõÕôÔúÚçÇ]' | sed 'y/áÁàÀãÃâÂéÉêÊíÍóÓõÕôÔúÚüÜçÇ/aAaAaAaAeEeEiIoOoOoOuUuUcC/'
```

---

But as for Tcl in particular *tclsh*, how can I represent the same effect as above without Unix-Like commands. Has as???

In particular I want first to know how we could change the strange characters from within a variable, like this:

```
# This sentence is in Brazilian Portuguese
set text "Tcl e sh são muito sensíveis ao espaço em branco."
```

If anyone wants to introduce other methods in *tclsh* to replace accents and cedillas in filenames. This is also valid for this question as I need both to understand if you can do this in pure Tcl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [string map](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) :

```
set text "Tcl e sh são muito sensíveis ao espaço em branco."
set newtext [string map -nocase {ã a ç c í i} $text] ; #  non-exhaustive list
# Tcl e sh sao muito sensiveis ao espaco em branco.
```

Comment: for substitutions this package : [fileutil](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) and this command `::fileutil::replaceInFile` (not tested)

Answer (score 3):

One nice way of doing this is with the aid of the [`unicode` normalization package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/stringprep/unicode.html) in tcllib. The key is that there is Normalization Form D (decomposed) which has all characters become simple ASCII (if applicable) and separate composing accents.

```
package require unicode 

set text "Tcl e sh são muito sensíveis ao espaço em branco."

set s [unicode::normalizeS D $text]
# trim out the composing chars (well, non-ascii because I'm lazy) 
set trimmed [regsub -all {[^\u0000-\u00ff]} $s {}]

puts "Before: $text"
puts "After:  $trimmed"
```

Which produces this output:

```
Before: Tcl e sh são muito sensíveis ao espaço em branco.
After:  Tcl e sh sao muito sensiveis ao espaco em branco.
```

If you have to work with really non-Latin texts (e.g., Arabic or Korean) then you need a narrower filter to remove the composing characters. I just couldn't  be bothered to look up the composing accent range I'm Unicode.

Comment: It is good to know that there is more than one alternative to perform the same task. Thank you for your cooperation in my question, even though I have already voted.